# wpf control for entering lists of items, similar to yahoo or facebook send-to text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a wpf control to enter a list of items similar to how you enter addresses in yahoo mail or in facebook.

It allows you to type in a name, displays a list of matches, once you select one it shows the selected item with a box around it.  After each item is added they are treated as a single entry allowing you to delete the entry or edit the entry.

Actually i just entered the tags for this post here on stack overflow and they do the same kind of entry i'm looking for.

I'm looking for any similar wpf control out there to get me started, i was not able to find anything. Can anyone point me to a similar control.

Comment: Here is pretty good working poc - http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/Demo/AutoComplete.zip  Comments or fixes are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The `TokenizedTextBox` in the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) is such a control, but it was cut from the latest release (1.6.0.0). It is in the *Main* branch in beta though, so you could try it out and provide feedback while you're at it.

Comment: That's close but not exactly what i'm looking for, i'll use it for reference.  I've got a pretty good sample going.  I'll post the code when it's to a good state.